# How can I delete all lines in a file using vi?

Tags: vi

How can I delete all lines in a file using vi?

At moment I do that using something like this to remove all lines in a file:

```
echo > test.txt
```

How can I delete all lines using `vi`?

**Note:**
Using `dd` is not a good option. There can be many lines.

Comment: I think dG should work.

Comment: @MadTux, only if you start on the first line. `1GdG` would work from anywhere.

Comment: `echo | test.txt` is not a valid command, unless `test.txt` is an executable script.  I'm guessing you mean `echo >test.txt` instead?

Comment: You are right @tripleee

Comment: Note that *not* using `vi`, `>test.txt` is sufficient to truncate it to zero length - no `echo` needed.

Comment: On the command line prefer `rm test.txt;touch test.txt` The echo creates a file with 1 character (new line) in it. While touch creates an empty file.

Comment: Depending upon the circumstances, you might be better off using `logrotate(8)` instead.  Why do you want to delete all lines in the file?

Comment: ``ggVG`` puts the whole file into a visual block. A simple `d` afterwards deletes the block. Using ``j``, ``k`` etc. one can adapt the visual block. Using ``o``, the cursor jumps to the block's other end.

Answer (score 646, accepted):

In `vi` do

```
:1,$d
```

to delete all lines.

The `:` introduces a command (and moves the cursor to the bottom).
The `1,$` is an indication of which lines the following command (`d`) should work on. In this case the range from line one to the last line (indicated by `$`, so you don't need to know the number of lines in the document).
The final `d` stands for delete the indicated lines.

There is a shorter form (`:%d`) but I find myself never using it. The `:1,$d` can be more easily "adapted" to e.g. `:4,$-2d` leaving only the first 3 and last 2 lines, deleting the rest.

Comment: Pro tip. No more `ESC+dd+dd+dd+dd+dd+dd+dd+dd+dd+dd+dd+dd+dd+dd+dd+dd...`

Comment: @rdev5 try `.` next time to repeat a command

Comment: Even with `:%d` and enter, its way too many strokes. I am trying to get into vim but without vim ctrl + a and del button is much more simpler than what vim provides for this. Just two strokes(ctrl+a, del) unlike `:%d` which has 4 strokes including the enter command

Answer (score 248):

In vi I use

```
:%d
```

where

- `:` tells vi to go in command mode
- `%` means all the lines
- `d` : delete

On the command line,

```
> test.txt
```

will do also.

What is the problem with dd?

```
dd if=/dev/null of=test.txt
```

where

- `/dev/null` is a special 0 byte file
- `if` is the input file
- `of` is the ouput file

Comment: I was thinking that using `dd` i need pess for every line on file.

Comment: Good. It's more simple than i expected...

Comment: You need to distinguish between `dd` the vi command (which the OP meant) and `dd` the utility, which you give an example of.  Also, `> test.txt` may not work as expected in non-bash shells (e.g. zsh).

Comment: @depquid Oups! now I come to think of it...

Comment: @Archemar I'm guessing you could just replace it with `cat /dev/null > test.txt`, even though it's a little longer.

Comment: Or `: >test.txt` which is only very marginally longer.

Comment: This is nicely explained

Comment: @Cold You can use dd to remove all the lines from all the files on the partition. That's possibly a little overkill, however.

Answer (score 66):

I'd recommend that you just do this (should work in any POSIX-compliant shell):

```
> test.txt
```

If you really want to do it with vi, you can do:

- 1G (go to first line)
- dG (delete to last line)

Comment: I want delete all in one time, If i have 10000000000000 lines, using dG i will need use dG how many times?

Comment: @Cold: ...once?

Comment: `G` represents last line.  If you are on the first line (`gg`), `dG` tells vi to remove all the lines from current line (first line) to the last line.  So, you do it in one shot.

Comment: once @ChrisDown.

Comment: `gg` is vim specific. It's `1G` in traditional vi.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks for the note, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Your shell syntax is dependent on configuration for some shells. Both bash and zsh (zsh by default) interactive shells can wait for input on STDIN after receiving that command and an additional <CTRL>+D is necessary to actually clear the file. The ability to run that is also dependent on CLOBBER settings. `>| test.txt < /dev/null` is somewhat more robust as it will always clobber the file and avoid waiting for input on interactive terminals.

Comment: @Caleb: Like I said, in any *POSIX-compliant* shell. :-) Neither of those two situations are POSIX-complaint.

Answer (score 35):

If your cursor is on the first line (if not, type: `gg` or `1G`), then you can just use `dG`. It will delete all lines from the current line to the end of file. So to make sure that you'll delete all the lines from the file, you may mix both together, which would be: `ggdG` (while in command mode).

Or `%d` in Ex mode, command-line example: `vim +%d foo.bar`.

Related: [How I can delete in VIM all text from current line to end of file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124315/how-i-can-delete-in-vim-all-text-from-current-line-to-end-of-file)

Comment: +1 for being more ergonomic than :1,$d.  Not that our fingers aren't wired for typing colon all the time now, anyway ;)

Comment: Upvoted. `dG` is what I always use.

Comment: I find this (`ggdG`) the easiest method in vim. The reason this answer isn't upvoted as others is that `gg` is non-existent in pure vi?

Comment: There are of course other similar variations if you're not already at the top of the file, such as `1GdG` or `Gd1G`.  But if you're using `vim`, then `ggdG` is the easiest to type.

Answer (score 35):

I'm a lazy dude, and I like to keep it simple. `ggdG` is five keystrokes including `Shift`

`gg` goes to the first line in the file, `d` is the start of the `d`elete verb and `G` is the movement to go to the bottom of the file. Verbosely, it's go to the beginning of the file and delete everything until the end of the tile.

Comment: rsrs. I'm lazy too and use `:$d` or `:1,$d` is the faster way (I write less characters) kkk

Comment: `:%d` is good alternative, since you only use 5 keystrokes that way too.

Comment: @TankorSmash `gg` is a `vim` command, not `vi`.

Comment: good catch, my mistake

Answer (score 13):

Go to the beginning of the file and press <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.

Answer (score 7):

I always use `ggVG`

- `gg` jumps to the start of the current editing file
- `V` (capitalized v) will select the current line. In this case the first line of the current editing file
- `G` (capitalized g) will jump to the end of the file. In this case, since I selected the first line, `G` will select the whole text in this file.

Then you can simply press `d` or `x` to delete all the lines.

Comment: If you use `d` vertically, it automatically applies linewise. `dl` deletes a character to the right, `dj` deletes a line down, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution:

```
truncate -s 0 file
```

Comment: Not really simpler than `>file` but OK.

Comment: Seem to be a good method, but the target is doing it using vi. Tks

Answer (score 3):

note that in your question, `echo > test.txt` creates a file with a single line break in it, not an empty file.

From the shell, consider using `echo -n > test.txt` or `: > test.txt`.

While I'd generally use a vi editing command (I use `ggdG`), you can also call out to the shell with a reference to the current file like so:

```
:!:>%
```

It's nearly as concise as `ggdG`, but harder to type, and you also have to confirm that you want to reload the modified file, so I don't particularly recommend it in this case, but knowing how to use shell commands from vi like this is useful.

breaking it down:

- `:` initiate a vi command
- `!` initate a shell command
- `:` this is a shell builtin command with empty output
- `>` redirect the output
- `%` vi substitutes this with the name of the current file

The suggested `:1,$d` is also a good one of course, and just while I'm at it there's also `1GdG`

Comment: `:!:>%` is also dangerous as `vi` doesn't escape the file name for the shell (don't do it when editing a file called `$(reboot)` for instance). You'd need something `:call system(":>" . shellescape(expand("%")))`

Answer (score 0):

I do a `dgg`, which deletes all lines from cursor (which is typically EOF when you open a file) to the top, which is the quickest.

Answer (score -1):

I type `gg` to reach the top of the lines and then do a `100 dd`. This brings the pointer to the top line of editor and clears 100 lines from there. You may have to adjust the number to add more lines if the file is lengthier.

Answer (score -1):

```
> file.txt
```

You don't even have to open vi unless you really want to.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange site. Please review the [help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) for information on how to best post this site. We want to cultivate informative and unique questions and answers on this site. Your answer is identical to other answers and comments on this post. Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/499261/edit) your post to be a more unique and informative answer please. Thank you!

Comment: Besides, the point of the question is ... "using vi"