# How can I delete a file using the Vim editor

Tags: vim

I have a file testfile.xml that I want to open with Vim and delete in command mode

Comment: `:!rm testfile.xml`?

Comment: to delete content : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161821/how-can-i-delete-all-lines-in-a-file-using-vi

Comment: `vi` is not a tool to delete file, `rm` and `find` are as well as backup tools.

Comment: This question is a better fit for the Vi and Vim site https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 14):

Another way to interactively delete files is to use

```
:E
```

or

```
:Ex
```

for ex(ploring) the file directory. There you have an interactive window that will guide you. Once you select the entry you want deleted, use

```
Shift-D
```

confirm with

```
y  
return
```

---

This is what it looks like at the top in my window in explorer mode:

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v140)
"   C:\Users\cbkrd\Desktop
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:exec
" ============================================================================
```

Comment: `:E` resulted in `E464: Ambiguous use of user-defined command`, but `:Ex` worked fine.

Answer (score 12):

There are many ways:

1. Using the intercative shell in vim

   When in the editor -

   ```
   :sh
   rm textfile.xml
   ```
2. Using Bang(!)

   As DopeGhoti suggested -

   ```
   :!rm textfile.xml
   ```
3. From [this link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Delete_files_with_a_Vim_command).

   Add this to your `~/.vimrc`

   ```
   command! -complete=file -nargs=1 Remove :echo 'Remove: '.'<f-args>'.' '.(delete(<f-args>) == 0 ? 'SUCCEEDED' : 'FAILED')
   ```

   Then,in vim,

   ```
   :Remove testfile.xml
   ```
4. Again from the same link in #3

   Use this command:

   ```
   :call delete(expand('%')) | bdelete!
   ```

Answer (score 8):

To delete the file, execute `:!rm %`. `%` expands to the file's name. Vim doesn't automatically delete the buffer, but you can manually do so with `:bd`.

To verify that the file has been deleted, execute `!ls`.

Answer (score 4):

As Yash states: there are many ways. But the shortest one,

`:echo delete(@%)`

only appears hidden, only at the end of Yash's link:

> I don't understand why you would use all those commands and functions.
>
> Why not `:echo delete(filename)`? Or, if you want to delete file and
>   wipeout buffer, which I guess happens very rarely, you may write `:echo delete(@%)`,
>   and if successfull -- `:bw!`.

With `echo` (instead of `call`) you see the result directly, 0 or -1.

---

`:!rm %` by @Justin is probably the same, but there is a screen switch and the "no longer available" message -- with `delete()` it is smoother.

And I don't understand what `rm` is *filtering* here...

---

The whole idea makes mostly sense if you want to sort out a bunch of files:

`vim $(find -size -100c -type f)`

If you want to delete/keep some of these small files. you can `:n[ext]` through them and delete them directly. The `:echo delete(@%)` should maybe only be mapped temporarily, because it is dangerous. I lost a help file, and renamed another, while experimenting with "%".

Comment: It is also cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

mv is safer than rm:

```
com!  -nargs=? -complete=file T call Trash_by_viM(<f-args>)
            " 0 or 1 arguments are allowed
fun! Trash_by_viM(...) abort
    if a:0 > 0   "  有传参
    " if a:1   之前用这行, 不行, 因为if 'abc' 等于if FALSE,  if '1abc' 才等于if TRUE
        exe '! mv'  a:1  '~/.t/'..a:1..'__moved_by_vim'
        echo "moved"  a:1
    el
        write
        exe '! mv' expand("%:p")  '~/.t/'..expand("%:p:t")..'__moved_by_vim'
        echo "moved" expand("%:p")
        bwipeout!
    en
endf
```